# Jquery form-calculator with inline click to be cleaned up

Tags: jquery, forms, onchange

My horrible form has all inline clicks. I was wondering if anyone can help me to clean up this mess as I need to run this properly.
On Fido I got it working only with the inline  which is terrible.
I hope someone could help!

http://jsfiddle.net/HdhCr/10/

**INLINE JS**

```
    function calc_total() {
        f=document.etg_p_print_form;
        t=document.etg_p_print_form.total_price;
        tt=0;

        for(i=1;i<17;i++)
        {
            if (f.elements['abo_single['+i+']'])
            {

                if(f.elements['abo_single['+i+']'].length>0)
                {
                    if(f.elements['abo_single['+i+']'][0].checked==true)
                    {
                        var tpr = f.elements['price_abo['+i+']'].value*f.elements['quantity['+i+']'].value;
                        var tpr2 = f.elements['price_abo['+i+']'].value*f.elements['quantity['+i+']'].value;
                        tpr_repl=number_format(tpr);
                        tpr_repl_num=tpr_repl.lastIndexOf('.');
                        f.elements['sum['+i+']'].value=tpr_repl.substring(0,tpr_repl_num)+'.'+tpr_repl.substring(tpr_repl_num+1,tpr_repl.length);
                        tt +=tpr2;
                    } else {
                        var tpr = f.elements['price_single['+i+']'].value*f.elements['quantity['+i+']'].value;
                        var tpr2 = f.elements['price_single['+i+']'].value*f.elements['quantity['+i+']'].value;
                        tpr_repl=number_format(tpr);
                        tpr_repl_num=tpr_repl.lastIndexOf('.');
                        f.elements['sum['+i+']'].value=tpr_repl.substring(0,tpr_repl_num)+'.'+tpr_repl.substring(tpr_repl_num+1,tpr_repl.length);

                        tt +=tpr2;
                    }
                } else {
                    if(f.elements['abo_single['+i+']'].value=='abo')
                    {
                        var tpr = f.elements['price_abo['+i+']'].value*f.elements['quantity['+i+']'].value;
                        var tpr2 = f.elements['price_abo['+i+']'].value*f.elements['quantity['+i+']'].value;
                        tpr_repl=number_format(tpr);
                        tpr_repl_num=tpr_repl.lastIndexOf('.');
                        f.elements['sum['+i+']'].value=tpr_repl.substring(0,tpr_repl_num)+'.'+tpr_repl.substring(tpr_repl_num+1,tpr_repl.length);
                        tt +=tpr2;
                    } else {
                        var tpr = f.elements['price_single['+i+']'].value*f.elements['quantity['+i+']'].value;
                        var tpr2 = f.elements['price_single['+i+']'].value*f.elements['quantity['+i+']'].value;
                        tpr_repl=number_format(tpr);
                        tpr_repl_num=tpr_repl.lastIndexOf('.');
                        f.elements['sum['+i+']'].value=tpr_repl.substring(0,tpr_repl_num)+'.'+tpr_repl.substring(tpr_repl_num+1,tpr_repl.length);
                        tt +=tpr2;
                    }
                }
            } 
        }
        tt_repl=number_format(tt);
        tt_repl_num=tt_repl.lastIndexOf('.');
        t.value=tt_repl.substring(0,tt_repl_num)+'.'+tt_repl.substring(tt_repl_num+1,tt_repl.length);
    }

    function number_format(val)
        {
            var nval='';
            var nnval='';
            var val=val.toFixed(2);
            for(ii=0;ii<val.length;ii++)
            {
                var tval=eval(ii+1);

                pos=eval(val.length-tval);
                nval += val.substr(pos,1);

                var test_val=eval(tval);
                var test_val=eval(test_val/3);
                if(test_val==test_val.toFixed(2) && tval!=val.length && eval(test_val)!=1)
                {
                    nval += '\'';
                }
            }
            for(z=0;z<nval.length;z++)
            {
                var ntval=eval(z+1);
                var npos=eval(nval.length-ntval);
                nnval += nval.substr(npos,1);
            }
            return nnval;
        }
</script>
```

**HTML**

```
<form action=" " method="post" name="etg_p_print_form"  class="form-calculator">
<input type="radio" name="abo_single[1]" value="abo" checked onChange="calc_total();" onClick="calc_total();" />
<input type="hidden" name="price_abo[1]" value="529" />
<br>
<input type="radio" name="abo_single[1]" value="single" onChange=";calc_total();" onClick="calc_total();" />
<input type="hidden" name="price_single[1]" value="90" />
<br>
how many?
<input type="text" class="input" name="quantity[1]" value="0" size="2" maxlength="2" onChange="if(isNaN(this.value)) { alert('HELLO'); this.value=0; } calc_total();" />
<br>
   <br> 
price<input type="hidden" name="tit_prod[1]" value="EurotaxListe PKW" />
529.00
<input type="text" class="input" name="sum[1]" value="0.-" readonly onChange="calc_total();" />
<br>

<p>Total
<input type="text" name="total_price" value="0.-" readonly  onChange="calc_total();" />
 </p>
</form>
```

Comment: What is it you don't know how to do?

Comment: my fiddle won't work unless the js code is inline. why?

Comment: You mean in a separate file? [This works fine for me](http://jsfiddle.net/RHuYs/). Do you mean that simply removing all the `onChange="calc_total();"` suddenly stops `calc_total()` from being called on change? In that case, I assume you realized that it would, and yet I see no hint of an attempt to replace those inline calls with anything else in your code...?

Comment: @DavidHedlund I tried to create a function .on change and another one on.click but but did't work.

Comment: We haven't seen it, though. If you showed it maybe we could have pointed out what was wrong with it. Always show what you've tried, don't just write "fix my code, please".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you just want to strip out inline `onClick` attributes, this will do it:

```
$('form.form-calculator input').on('change', function() {
    calc_total();
}
```

**EDIT**

```
$('form.form-calculator input').on('change,click', function() {
    if ($(this).val() === 0) {
        alert('HELLO');
        this.value=0;
    }

    calc_total();
}
```

Comment: onChange=";calc_total();" and 

onClick=";calc_total();" how can make the click one too?

Comment: @DD77: `.on('change,click', calc_total)`

Comment: and what about onChange="if(isNaN(this.value)) { alert('HELLO'); this.value=0; } calc_total();"

Comment: This is where I would invite you to stop for a moment to read the code that has actually been posted and see if you can understand what it does. Once you do, you will be able to figure out how to make the adaptations you need. If there's anything you don't understand, ask about that, and we'll help you. I recommend that you always try to understand the code you're using.

Comment: this was a lazy one from me, sorry for wasting your time. really appreciate your call. I'm learning bit by bit.